# Cant we put a ember concurrency task in glimmer component getter, which is tracking the components arguments

Tags: ember.js, glimmer.js, ember-concurrency

-- when an ember concurrency task is called glimmer components getter then it runs in infinite loop.

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { task } from 'ember-concurrency';

export default class UserTableComponent extends Component {
  @service store;
  @tracked users;

  get taskStatus() {
    let params = {
      'account_id':this.args.account,
      'page':this.args.page
    }
    this.getUsersTask.perform(params);

  }


  @task(function*(params) {
      let recordsWithMeta = yield this.store.query('user', params);
      this.users= recordsWithMeta.toArray();
    }) getUsersTask;

}
```

user-table.hbs

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="first">Name</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#if this.taskStatus.isRunning}}
    <tr>
      <td >
        <div class="h-64">
          {{ui-kit/loader}}
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {{else}}
    {{#each @users as |user|}}

    {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Above component is called somewhere in template and passing account and page dynamic.

```
<UserTable 
  @account={{this.account}}
  @page={{this.page}}
  >          
</UserTable>
```

Note: it runs in infinite loop.

Comment: I couldn't get this. Are you calling `taskStatus` from the template? And actually `taskStatus` is a getter but not returning anything?

Comment: @ykaragol yes it is used in template and it's return the task. just updated post

Comment: @kdhayal Did you fix it??

Answer (score 0):

I've found two things to change. But not sure if they will be enough to make it work.

First point,

`{{#each @users as |user|}}` is equivalent to `this.args.users`. But `users` array is defined on the component. So it has to be changed to `{{#each this.users as |user|}}`

Second point,

`taskStatus` is not returning anything. So `{{#if this.taskStatus.isRunning}}` will be `false` every time. The correct check would be `{{#if this.getUsersTask.isRunning}}`, because `isRunning` is a property of the task.
But when you changed to `{{#if this.getUsersTask.isRunning}}`, it will not work since no one triggering `getUserTask`. I think you can initiate that task in one of lifecycle hooks (such as `didInsertElement`).